Interaction plots with Fixest class models
I am working with a fixest class object (feols for OLS). I would like to plot interaction regression models. I like the interact_plot function from interactions package but it unfortunately does not support the fixest class object.
I could take either of these two alternatives.

An interaction plot package that supports fixest class objects
How to manually extract elements from my fixest model, create a new object, and plug it into the interact_plot function. How could I do this.

Best
